# ¿Qué debo hacer para migrar un proyecto PHP 7.1 a 8.2?

Tags: php7, php8

Buenas tardes con todos,
Estoy en un proyecto para migrar un proyecto en PHP 7.1 a PHP 8.2, pero no tengo claro qué es lo que debo hacer para lograrlo, por lo que cualquier ayuda, link o consejo sería perfecto

Comment: Es ambigua la pregunta, hay demasiados cambios entre la 7.1 a la 8.2 para poder describirlo en una respuesta. PHP ofrece documentación y [guías de migración](https://www.php.net/manual/en/appendices.php). Creo que la forma más rápida sería colocar el código directamente a PHP 8.2 e ir reparando los errores a medida que van surgiendo. Obviamente el nuevo código escribirlo a nivel de PHP 8.2.

Comment: Buenas tardes, amigo. Para indicar un poco el contexto, un cliente mío tiene una página web alojada en cPanel la cual está con PHP 7.1
El problema es que el proveedor actualizó el servidor a PHP 8.2 y eso trajo que mi código quedara obsoleto y mi página no se muestre.
¿Tendría que revisar el código de todos los archivos y actualizarlos con las guías entonces?¿No tengo que instalar nada sino solo cambiar el código que tienen?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Claro, mi necesidad (Más que problema) sería saber cuál es el proceso para actualizar un proyecto trabajado en PHP 7.1 a PHP 8.2, ya que nunca he tenido proyectos relacionados y desconozco si se trata de actualizar mediante un programa/programas o mediante cambiar el código de todos los archivos uno por uno.

Comment: Si el sitio fue hecho por un framework, (Laravel, CodeIgniter, ...) tendrás que volver a generarlo con el framework actualizado. Si no se usó un framework, entonces tendrás que actualizar manualmente todos los archivos involucrados en errores. Mira el log de errores de PHP del sitio para ver dónde está rompiéndose. A veces los hostings traen varias versiones de PHP, verifica si aún puedes asignarle al sitio a una versión anterior.

Comment: Revisando los archivos, noté que el sitio fue desarrollado en Laravel 5.7 (Que también debe actualizarse),¿Me podrías apoyar explicándome más a lo que te refieres con volver a generarlo con el framework actualizado?